# RecyclerView Checkbox state in android bottomsheet

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, radio-button, bottom-sheet

I have an activity in which there is a button that shows a bottom sheet. In That bottom sheet, the recyclerView appears on the bottomsheet when the bottom sheet gets loaded.
RecyclerView Item has a radio button. Whenever I select an item, the radio button set to checked = true otherwise false, and the bottom sheet is dismissed. It works fine. But the bug is if I again open the bottom sheet, all the radio button are checked to false.
E.g. **I have a total of 5 items (0-4) in my recyclerview. If I select the 3rd position of the adapter, the radio button gets checked and the bottom sheet is dismissed. If I want to change my adapter's position i.e from 3rd to 2nd, the bottom sheet is opening but all radio buttons of the adapter are unchecked INCLUDING the 3rd position.**
How can I manage that radio button's state when the bottom sheet reopens or how to set the state for default position? *(in Java)*

Comment: What kind of Bottom sheet you are using? Modal(BottomSheetDialogFragment) or Persistent(BottomSheetDialog with CoordinatorLayout)?

Comment: BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: Then you can keep a boolean list to track the checked items. When am item is checked, keep that element true. Store the list in your activity/sharedpreferences